# Hide Content from certain users on Sharepoint online using CSS/JS

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, navigation, hide-elements

I want to hide the side navigation from only certain users but we have been specifallly instructed to not mess with the master page. we are only allowed to use CSS or Javascript

Comment: Publishing feature enables on site or not?

Comment: do you want to hide Navigation from users based on permission level or any other criteria?

Comment: No need for script if you put the CSS <style> in Content Editor WebPart and use the WebPart-properties Target Audience setting to only include that WebPart for ... a targeted audience

Answer (score 1):

You create a separate Java script file to write the logic and give reference this java script file in master page.
or else you can using existing referred javascript file

```
    var SideMenu = {

    Hide: function (groupname) {

           $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl+"/_api/Web/currentUser/groups?$filter=Title eq '"+groupname+"'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.d.results.length>=1){
                  $("#sideNavBox").hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }  
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
        SideMenu.Hide("GroupName1");
    });
```

Here GroupName1 you can assign your group name for which you want to hide side menu.